# Java program to create Greek waves in JPanel

Tags: java, graphics

I'm new to Java programming, and I wish if there is a way to design greek waves in JPanel in Java. I'm attaching an image to explain better what I mean by Greek waves:

[image: Greek waves photo]

I tried to use a *for* loop since a wave would be enough to design, but I got stuck at using only QuadCurve2D.Double, since I can't implement other methods. Any suggestion or help?
Thanks in advance.
This is what I've done so far:

[image: Attempt]

P.S. sorry for not showing photos, stackoverflow doesn't allow me to.

Comment: The problem (apart from deleting the previously closed, exact duplicate, of this question and posting it again  - which demonstrates that you're not paying attention to the posting guide lines) is that this is a very complex problem.  The shape is made up a number of smaller shapes, and even if you get the "primary" wave to work, in order to repeat it, the shapes need to overlap each other, very difficult to do. I would suggest that your time would be better spent studying the [2D Graphics Trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/TOC.html), pay attention to the section of geometry

Comment: @MadProgrammer the comment after closing my last topic was that it was due to lack of explanation. After reading for re-opening possibilities, I chose to post it (this wasn't the version that was closed) with additional features. I've spent some time on that topic (2D Graphics Trail in Oracle), but since I'm a beginner, I posted it here to get some advices. I know that my approach is far away from a good one. Otherwise, I wouldn't have asked for help. Thanks anyway!

Comment: *"I've spent some time on that topic"* - here's part of the problem, how much time?  What have you tried? What research have you done? [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). What we don't want to do is run over ground you've already been over or worse, present you with a solution which you don't have the technical skill/knowledge to understand or implement - happens way too often. Not trying to be a a** hole here, I'm trying to help you avoid common issues 

Comment: I've spent about two months on it. I'm a computer engineering student with 3.9/4.0 GPA, not that good in computer graphics, though. From that article, I have enhanced my skills in GeneralPath, AffineTransform, Area, BasicStroke, but I doubt if these are enough to solve the aforementioned problem. If you have any solution that you want to share, I would be glad to learn from it. Thank you very much for your helpful responses!

Comment: You do not give any code whatsoever either -- if you want to ask for help please make sure to also provide the necessary code in order for us to understand your issue. Also, I recommend for you really research more and try to stimulate a result that is close to the one you want. And then from there we can come and help.

Comment: There's someone who has helped with my issues even though the code was missing. I've already accepted that solution. But thanks for the suggestions, I'll be more accurate next time.

Answer (score 2):

Sooo, this was a long and difficult journey...

First, I took your image and imported in to a vector image editor.  I spent a lot of time creating the basic shape and then determining the best option for creating a single "repeated" shape, which got me to something like...

[image]

I then used [Flamingo SVG Transcoder](https://github.com/ebourg/flamingo-svg-transcoder) to convert it to "Java Graphics 2D" code, which got me...

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import static java.awt.Color.*;
import static java.awt.MultipleGradientPaint.CycleMethod.*;
import static java.awt.MultipleGradientPaint.ColorSpaceType.*;

/**
 * This class has been automatically generated using
 * <a href="http://ebourg.github.io/flamingo-svg-transcoder/">Flamingo SVG transcoder</a>.
 */
public class GreekWave {

    /**
     * Paints the transcoded SVG image on the specified graphics context. You
     * can install a custom transformation on the graphics context to scale the
     * image.
     * 
     * @param g Graphics context.
     */
    public static void paint(Graphics2D g) {
        Shape shape = null;
        
        float origAlpha = 1.0f;
        Composite origComposite = g.getComposite();
        if (origComposite instanceof AlphaComposite) {
            AlphaComposite origAlphaComposite = (AlphaComposite)origComposite;
            if (origAlphaComposite.getRule() == AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER) {
                origAlpha = origAlphaComposite.getAlpha();
            }
        }
        
        java.util.LinkedList<AffineTransform> transformations = new java.util.LinkedList<AffineTransform>();
        

        // 

        // _0

        // _0_0
        shape = new GeneralPath();
        ((GeneralPath) shape).moveTo(97.5, 21.0);
        ((GeneralPath) shape).curveTo(97.5, 31.0, 86.56, 39.14, 78.5, 39.0);
        ((GeneralPath) shape).curveTo(66.97, 38.91, 73.5, 24.0, 69.5, 25.0);
        ((GeneralPath) shape).curveTo(60.42, 25.44, 49.75, 35.5, 50.5, 47.0);
        ((GeneralPath) shape).curveTo(52.0, 65.0, 65.35, 68.16, 72.5, 68.0);
        ((GeneralPath) shape).curveTo(81.97, 66.26, 90.26, 61.16, 98.0, 54.49);
        ((GeneralPath) shape).curveTo(98.0, 69.47, 98.0, 82.35, 98.0, 85.0);
        ((GeneralPath) shape).lineTo(0.0, 85.0);
        ((GeneralPath) shape).curveTo(0.0, 82.35, 0.0, 69.47, 0.0, 54.49);
        ((GeneralPath) shape).curveTo(0.26, 54.26, 0.53, 54.03, 0.79, 53.8);
        ((GeneralPath) shape).curveTo(23.75, 33.61, 42.07, 0.0, 72.5, 0.0);
        ((GeneralPath) shape).curveTo(92.5, 1.0, 97.5, 11.0, 97.5, 21.0);
        ((GeneralPath) shape).closePath();

        g.setPaint(GRAY);
        g.fill(shape);

    }

    /**
     * Returns the X of the bounding box of the original SVG image.
     * 
     * @return The X of the bounding box of the original SVG image.
     */
    public static int getOrigX() {
        return 0;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the Y of the bounding box of the original SVG image.
     * 
     * @return The Y of the bounding box of the original SVG image.
     */
    public static int getOrigY() {
        return 0;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the width of the bounding box of the original SVG image.
     * 
     * @return The width of the bounding box of the original SVG image.
     */
    public static int getOrigWidth() {
        return 98;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the height of the bounding box of the original SVG image.
     * 
     * @return The height of the bounding box of the original SVG image.
     */
    public static int getOrigHeight() {
        return 85;
    }
}
```

Now, to be honest, I don't need much of it, but the important part is this...

```
shape = new GeneralPath();
((GeneralPath) shape).moveTo(97.5, 21.0);
((GeneralPath) shape).curveTo(97.5, 31.0, 86.56, 39.14, 78.5, 39.0);
((GeneralPath) shape).curveTo(66.97, 38.91, 73.5, 24.0, 69.5, 25.0);
((GeneralPath) shape).curveTo(60.42, 25.44, 49.75, 35.5, 50.5, 47.0);
((GeneralPath) shape).curveTo(52.0, 65.0, 65.35, 68.16, 72.5, 68.0);
((GeneralPath) shape).curveTo(81.97, 66.26, 90.26, 61.16, 98.0, 54.49);
((GeneralPath) shape).curveTo(98.0, 69.47, 98.0, 82.35, 98.0, 85.0);
((GeneralPath) shape).lineTo(0.0, 85.0);
((GeneralPath) shape).curveTo(0.0, 82.35, 0.0, 69.47, 0.0, 54.49);
((GeneralPath) shape).curveTo(0.26, 54.26, 0.53, 54.03, 0.79, 53.8);
((GeneralPath) shape).curveTo(23.75, 33.61, 42.07, 0.0, 72.5, 0.0);
((GeneralPath) shape).curveTo(92.5, 1.0, 97.5, 11.0, 97.5, 21.0);
((GeneralPath) shape).closePath();
```

From this, I was able to create a simple class...

```
public class GreekWave extends Path2D.Double {

    public GreekWave() {
        moveTo(97.5, 21.0);
        curveTo(97.5, 31.0, 86.56, 39.14, 78.5, 39.0);
        curveTo(66.97, 38.91, 73.5, 24.0, 69.5, 25.0);
        curveTo(60.42, 25.44, 49.75, 35.5, 50.5, 47.0);
        curveTo(52.0, 65.0, 65.35, 68.16, 72.5, 68.0);
        curveTo(81.97, 66.26, 90.26, 61.16, 98.0, 54.49);
        curveTo(98.0, 69.47, 98.0, 82.35, 98.0, 85.0);
        lineTo(0.0, 85.0);
        curveTo(0.0, 82.35, 0.0, 69.47, 0.0, 54.49);
        curveTo(0.26, 54.26, 0.53, 54.03, 0.79, 53.8);
        curveTo(23.75, 33.61, 42.07, 0.0, 72.5, 0.0);
        curveTo(92.5, 1.0, 97.5, 11.0, 97.5, 21.0);
        closePath();
    }

    public Dimension getSize() {
        return new Dimension(98, 85);
    }
}
```

This is important, as `Path2D` is part of the `geom` or "shapes" API, which provides A LOT of really useful functionality, as well as been really, really easy to paint.

For example...

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class GreekWave extends Path2D.Double {

        public GreekWave() {
            moveTo(97.5, 21.0);
            curveTo(97.5, 31.0, 86.56, 39.14, 78.5, 39.0);
            curveTo(66.97, 38.91, 73.5, 24.0, 69.5, 25.0);
            curveTo(60.42, 25.44, 49.75, 35.5, 50.5, 47.0);
            curveTo(52.0, 65.0, 65.35, 68.16, 72.5, 68.0);
            curveTo(81.97, 66.26, 90.26, 61.16, 98.0, 54.49);
            curveTo(98.0, 69.47, 98.0, 82.35, 98.0, 85.0);
            lineTo(0.0, 85.0);
            curveTo(0.0, 82.35, 0.0, 69.47, 0.0, 54.49);
            curveTo(0.26, 54.26, 0.53, 54.03, 0.79, 53.8);
            curveTo(23.75, 33.61, 42.07, 0.0, 72.5, 0.0);
            curveTo(92.5, 1.0, 97.5, 11.0, 97.5, 21.0);
            closePath();
        }

        public Dimension getSize() {
            return new Dimension(98, 85);
        }
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private GreekWave greekWave = new GreekWave();

        public TestPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return greekWave.getSize();
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
            Rectangle bounds = greekWave.getBounds();
            int width = bounds.x + bounds.width;
            int height = bounds.y + bounds.height;
            int x = (getWidth() - width) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - height) / 2;
            g2d.translate(x, y);
            g2d.draw(greekWave);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

Now, you "could" try and simply "rubber stamping" the shape to create a repeating pattern, but this will create an issue.  The basic shape is closed, so any kind of "fill pattern" is probably going to end up looking weird.

Instead, we want to create a single, repeating, shape.  Remember what I said about the "shapes API"?  Basically, we can translate the core shape and "append" them to another, for example...

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class GreekWave extends Path2D.Double {

        public GreekWave() {
            moveTo(97.5, 21.0);
            curveTo(97.5, 31.0, 86.56, 39.14, 78.5, 39.0);
            curveTo(66.97, 38.91, 73.5, 24.0, 69.5, 25.0);
            curveTo(60.42, 25.44, 49.75, 35.5, 50.5, 47.0);
            curveTo(52.0, 65.0, 65.35, 68.16, 72.5, 68.0);
            curveTo(81.97, 66.26, 90.26, 61.16, 98.0, 54.49);
            curveTo(98.0, 69.47, 98.0, 82.35, 98.0, 85.0);
            lineTo(0.0, 85.0);
            curveTo(0.0, 82.35, 0.0, 69.47, 0.0, 54.49);
            curveTo(0.26, 54.26, 0.53, 54.03, 0.79, 53.8);
            curveTo(23.75, 33.61, 42.07, 0.0, 72.5, 0.0);
            curveTo(92.5, 1.0, 97.5, 11.0, 97.5, 21.0);
            closePath();
        }

        public Dimension getSize() {
            return new Dimension(98, 85);
        }
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private Area repeatedShape;

        public TestPane() {
            repeatedShape = new Area();
            GreekWave greekWave = new GreekWave();
            for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
                Shape translatedShape = greekWave.createTransformedShape(AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(index * greekWave.getSize().width, 0));
                repeatedShape.add(new Area(translatedShape));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            Rectangle bounds = repeatedShape.getBounds();
            int width = bounds.x + bounds.width;
            int height = bounds.y + bounds.height;
            return new Dimension(width, height);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
            Rectangle bounds = repeatedShape.getBounds();
            int width = bounds.x + bounds.width;
            int height = bounds.y + bounds.height;
            int x = (getWidth() - width) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - height) / 2;
            g2d.translate(x, y);
            g2d.draw(repeatedShape);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

Now, I have to admit, that ended up better then I though it would, now we can fill it.

You could just replace `g2d.draw(repeatedShape);` with `g2d.fill(repeatedShape);` (don't forget to specify a color first), but where's the fun in that.

You could make use of `GradientPait` or even a `TexturePaint` (see [Stroking and Filling Graphics Primitives](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/strokeandfill.html) for more details), but lets try something which might match the original image...

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class GreekWave extends Path2D.Double {

        public GreekWave() {
            moveTo(97.5, 21.0);
            curveTo(97.5, 31.0, 86.56, 39.14, 78.5, 39.0);
            curveTo(66.97, 38.91, 73.5, 24.0, 69.5, 25.0);
            curveTo(60.42, 25.44, 49.75, 35.5, 50.5, 47.0);
            curveTo(52.0, 65.0, 65.35, 68.16, 72.5, 68.0);
            curveTo(81.97, 66.26, 90.26, 61.16, 98.0, 54.49);
            curveTo(98.0, 69.47, 98.0, 82.35, 98.0, 85.0);
            lineTo(0.0, 85.0);
            curveTo(0.0, 82.35, 0.0, 69.47, 0.0, 54.49);
            curveTo(0.26, 54.26, 0.53, 54.03, 0.79, 53.8);
            curveTo(23.75, 33.61, 42.07, 0.0, 72.5, 0.0);
            curveTo(92.5, 1.0, 97.5, 11.0, 97.5, 21.0);
            closePath();
        }

        public Dimension getSize() {
            return new Dimension(98, 85);
        }
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private Area repeatedShape;

        public TestPane() {
            repeatedShape = new Area();
            GreekWave greekWave = new GreekWave();
            for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
                Shape translatedShape = greekWave.createTransformedShape(AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(index * greekWave.getSize().width, 0));
                repeatedShape.add(new Area(translatedShape));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            Rectangle bounds = repeatedShape.getBounds();
            int width = bounds.x + bounds.width;
            int height = bounds.y + bounds.height;
            return new Dimension(width, height);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
            Rectangle bounds = repeatedShape.getBounds();
            int width = bounds.x + bounds.width;
            int height = bounds.y + bounds.height;
            int x = (getWidth() - width) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - height) / 2;
            g2d.translate(x, y);
            g2d.draw(repeatedShape);

            g2d.setClip(repeatedShape);
            for (x = 0; x < getWidth(); x += 4) {
                g2d.drawLine(x, 0, x, getHeight());
            }

            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

Or, if you don't want the outline, remove `g2d.draw(repeatedShape);`...

[image]

So, when I tell you that the shapes API is REALLY important and REALLY powerful, I'm not exaggerate.

Now, this is has taken me the better part of half the day, so, before you start posting more comments, spend the time going through the [2D Graphics trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html) and supporting JavaDocs

Comment: Thank you a lot! I appreciate a lot the step-by-step explanation!